# Pandas find last positive value in each column and Replace NaN with that value

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'menu1': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, None, None], 
                  'menu2': [4, 4, None, 4, None, None, None], 
                  'menu3': [None, None, 9, 9, None, None, None]
                            })
df
```

For each column, I would like to find the last positive value and replace NAN with that value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'menu1': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], 
                  'menu2': [4, 4, None, 4, 4, 4, 4], 
                  'menu3': [None, None, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
                            })
df
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using interpolation method [`pandas.DataFrame.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) with specific options:

```
df.interpolate(limit_direction='forward', limit_area='outside')
```

- `limit_direction='forward'` - tells in what direction NaNs will be filled in
- `limit_area='outside'` - tells to only fill NaNs outside valid values (means that `NaN` should not be surrounded by valid values)

---

```
  menu1  menu2  menu3
0    5.0    4.0    NaN
1    5.0    4.0    NaN
2    5.0    NaN    9.0
3    5.0    4.0    9.0
4    5.0    4.0    9.0
5    5.0    4.0    9.0
6    5.0    4.0    9.0
```

Comment: Wow this is a neat use of interpolate.  +1

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df.ffill().where(df.ffill().notna() & df.bfill().isna(),df)
```

Output:

```
   menu1  menu2  menu3
0    5.0    4.0    NaN
1    5.0    4.0    NaN
2    5.0    NaN    9.0
3    5.0    4.0    9.0
4    5.0    4.0    9.0
5    5.0    4.0    9.0
6    5.0    4.0    9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'menu1': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, None, None], 
                  'menu2': [4, 4, None, 4, None, None, None], 
                  'menu3': [None, None, 9, 9, None, None, None]
                            })

# iterate through each column
for col in df.columns:
    # find the last non-null positive value
    last_value = None
    last_positive_index = -1
    for i in reversed(range(len(df[col]))):
        if pd.notna(df[col][i]) and df[col][i] > 0:
            last_value = df[col][i]
            last_positive_index = i
            break
    
    if last_positive_index > -1:
        # replace null values after the last positive value with the last positive value
        for i in range(last_positive_index, len(df[col])):
            if pd.isna(df[col][i]) and last_value is not None:
                df.at[i, col] = last_value
            elif last_value is not None and df[col][i] < 0:
                df.at[i, col] = last_value

# print the resulting dataframe
print(df)
```

### Edit 1

**dates as index**

```
import pandas as pd

# create the dataframe with a datetime index
dates = pd.date_range('2022-01-01', periods=7)
df = pd.DataFrame({'menu1': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, None, None], 
                  'menu2': [4, 4, None, 4, None, None, None], 
                  'menu3': [None, None, 9, 9, None, None, None]
                  }, index=dates)

# iterate through each column
for col in df.columns:
    # find the last non-null positive value
    last_value = None
    last_positive_index = None
    for date in reversed(df.index):
        if pd.notna(df.loc[date, col]) and df.loc[date, col] > 0:
            last_value = df.loc[date, col]
            last_positive_index = date
            break
    
    if last_positive_index is not None:
        # replace null values after the last positive value with the last positive value
        for date in df.loc[last_positive_index:].index:
            if pd.isna(df.loc[date, col]) and last_value is not None:
                df.at[date, col] = last_value
            elif last_value is not None and df.loc[date, col] < 0:
                df.at[date, col] = last_value

# print the resulting dataframe
print(df)
```

Comment: This code is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any suggestions when the index is Datetimeindex? Thanks.